# I want to create a dynamic array of objects, and retrive them

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:
I have two arrays[lab ,val] whose values are to be dynamicaly passed to object.
k is array to hold objects

```
var lab = ["1","2","3",4];
var val = ["sa","ma","pa","da"];
var k = [];
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)  {
   data[i] = {};             
   data[i].label = lab[i];
   data[i].value = val[i]; 
   k.push(data[i]) ;  
}

document.write(k.data[0]);  
document.write(" " + k.data[0] + "<br />");
```

Comment: What are you getting that you aren't wanting?

Comment: Where is the `data` variable come from? Just use `k[i] = {"label":label[i],"value":val[i]};` and omit the `.push()`.

Comment: Please add question and explan what "not working" means - what you expect and what does not happen/exact error you see (I removed "not working" from title as it does not belong there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already pushing the objects into an array, do it like this -

```
var lab = ["1","2","3",4];
var val = ["sa","ma","pa","da"];
var k = [];
var obj;    // it will hold temporary object references

for(var i=0; i<4; i++)  {
   obj = {};             
   obj.label = lab[i];
   obj.value = val[i]; 
   k.push(obj) ;  
}

document.write(k[0].label);    // index k, rather than the value it contains 
document.write(" " + k[0].value + "<br />");
```

Your code is not working because you are indexing the values that `k` stores, and your `data` variable isn't declared anywhere.

You can even shorten the `for` loop by directly pushing the objects into the array, which is a better way -

```
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)  {
   k.push({
       label: lab[i],
       value: val[i]
   }) ;  
}
```

In this way you won't even need the temporary object.

Comment: I have an array of structures in  c holding some values ,and i need to pass those values to javascript and send via html to embedded sys(which is the only way) , and retrive them there, ANy good suggestions other than this ,am not fluent to javascript.

Comment: @kelvin: I agree with Adam Rackis on this. It will be better if you expose your data structure using some sort of services to be consumed there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `data` variable is undeclared.  Try just declaring it before your loop, and, while you're there, consider changing the condition on your for loop to check the length of the array, rather than having it hard coded at 2.

```
var lab = ["1","2","3",4];
var val = ["sa","ma","pa","da"];
var k    = [],
    data = [];  // <----- here
for(var i = 0;  i < lab.length; i++)  {
   data[i] = {};             
   data[i].label = lab[i];
   data[i].value = val[i]; 
   k.push(data[i]) ;  
}
```

But really, what's the point of the `data` array?  It looks like it's just holding a duplicate of everything `k` has.  Why not just do:

```
var lab = ["1","2","3",4];
var val = ["sa","ma","pa","da"];
var k = [];

for(var i=0; i < lab.length; i++)  {
   k.push({
       label: lab[i],
       value: val[i]       
   });  
}
```

Comment: I have an array of structures in  c,and i need to pass those values to javascript , and retrive them ,will this work

Comment: @kelvin - certainly not.  I'm not even sure how one would go about passing an array of C structures into JavaScript.  I'm guessing you'd have to serialize them into JSON through some sort of web service.